# Best way to turn a list of lists into a more nested list of lists of lists with equal length?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to write a function that takes a list of lists, and return a list of lists of lists of equal size. For example, with `[[1,2], [0,1], [1,2,3], [0,1,2], [1,2,3,4]]` as input, the function should return `[[[1,2],[0,1]], [[1,2,3],[0,1,2]], [[1,2,3,4]]]`. I know the length of the longest list.

My first intuition was to use a list comprehension for this:

```
def nestedlenlist(biglist,maxlen):
    return [[lists for lists in biglist if len(lists) == n] for n in xrange(0,maxlen)]
```

I have two gripes with this:

1. It iterates `maxlen` times over the list, which can take some time with longer lists.
2. What if I didn't know the maximum length of the list?

A solution could involve `sorted`: first sort the list so that you only have to go over the list once, splitting it whenever `biglist[i]` and `biglist[i+1]` differ in size. But then I find myself looping and messing around with indices, which is something you generally want to avoid doing in Python.

So what is the fastest and most Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: I really don't get why people downvote questions for no reason.

Comment: Neither do I, must be because it's a beginner's question. (If there's something I should've done otherwise please tell me)

Comment: Well Python is very subjective, perhaps just saying _fastest_ or most _efficient_ is a better way to put it. If you want something _readable_, then say so. Or if you want a one liner list comprehension, you can say that too :D (which is a cool python feature btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you need is first to iterate the list, bucket each len of sublist into a group, and then simply put that all together into a list. This also sorts them. But if you wanted to go faster, you could do it unsorted.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def bucket_list(nested_list, sort=True):
    bucket = defaultdict(list)
    for sublist in nested_list:
        bucket[len(sublist)].append(sublist)
    return [v for k,v in sorted(bucket.items())] if sort else bucket.values()
```

Using it:

```
>>> bucket_list([[1,2], [0,1], [1,2,3], [0,1,2], [1,2,3,4]])
[[[1, 2], [0, 1]], [[1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2]], [[1, 2, 3, 4]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [1]: x =[[1,2], [0,1], [1,2,3], [0,1,2], [1,2,3,4]]

In [2]: result = {}

In [3]: for xx in x: result.setdefault(len(xx),[]).append(xx)

In [4]: result.values()
Out[4]: [[[1, 2], [0, 1]], [[1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2]], [[1, 2, 3, 4]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic = defaultdict(list)
>>> lis = [[1,2], [0,1], [1,2,3], [0,1,2], [1,2,3,4]]
>>> for item in lis:
...     dic[len(item)].append(item)
...     
>>> dic.values()  # use `sorted` if you want result to be sorted by `len`
[[[1, 2], [0, 1]], [[1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2]], [[1, 2, 3, 4]]]
```

Or using [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lis = [[1,2], [0,1], [1,2,3], [0,1,2], [1,2,3,4]]
>>> sorted_lis = sorted(lis, key=len)  #sort the list based on length of items
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted_lis, key=len)]  
[[[1, 2], [0, 1]], [[1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2]], [[1, 2, 3, 4]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure list comprehension solution, but not the best (I think):

```
origin = [[1, 2], [0, 1], [1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1]]


def list_of_lists(some_list):
    """
    This is a weird algorithm
    @type some_list: list
    @rtype : list
    @param some_list:
    """
    if len(some_list) % 2:
        return [[a, b] for a, b in zip(some_list[::2], (some_list[1::2]))] + [some_list[len(origin) - 1]]
    else:
        return [[a, b] for a, b in zip(some_list[::2], (some_list[1::2]))]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print list_of_lists(origin)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lens = [len(x) for x in biglist]
longest = max(lens)

# Need to make sure that the list of lists is not shallow copies
newlist = []
for n in range(longest):
    newlist.append 

for alist in biglist:
   x = len(alist) - 1
   newlist[x].append(alist)
```